# Does hashchanges affect onbefore unload

Tags: jquery, onbeforeunload, hashchange

I have been searching and have not found any thing about how onbeforeunload is affected by hash changes. I have a jquery based single page app and am using hash changes to fire view changes. However I want to avoid having the user refresh the page, accidentally closing tabs etc..

Does anyone have experience with this? I have googled but not found any general discussion only plugin specific git hub pages where both are mentioned on the same page.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

No, hash changes are assumed to navigate on the current page and do not fire an onbeforeunload event.

You can safely use onbeforeunload to detect the user attempting to close the page or navigate away from it.